# Laravel 5.6: The values under comparison must be of the same type

Tags: php, validation, comparison, numeric, laravel-5.6

We recently upgaded Laravel from 5.5 to 5.6 I have validation rules:

```
return [
            'min_price' => ['numeric', 'nullable', 'min:0'],
            'max_price' => ['numeric', 'nullable', 'min:0', 'gt:min_price'],
]
```

It throws an error in case if

1. min_price = null, max_price = 100
2. min_price = 0, max_price = 99.99
3. min_price = 12.50, max_price = 100
4. min_price = 12.50, max_price = null
   It says:

```
ERROR: The values under comparison must be of the same type "exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The values under comparison must be of the same type at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php:1659)
[stacktrace]
#0 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php(849): Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator->requireSameType(12.50, 100)
```

It says, that both fields should have the same type, so it can't compare integer and float and can't ignore nullable fields.
The issue is with methods `validateGt`, `validateLt`, `validateGte`, `validateLte` in trait `ValidatesAttributes`. Is there some how I can extand or override that trait?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no obvious solution, I decided to create my own validator and don't use the one that Laravel offers:

```
class ServiceProvider extends BaseServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        ValidatorFacade::extend('greater_than', Validator::class.'@validateGreaterThan');
        ValidatorFacade::replacer('greater_than', function ($message, $a, $b, $parameters) {
            $attributes = trans('validation.attributes');
            $other = $parameters[0];
            $other = isset($attributes[$other]) ? $attributes[$other] : $other;

            return str_replace(':field', $other, $message);
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

And used it in validations rules like this

```
return [
            'min_price' => ['numeric', 'nullable', 'min:0'],
            'max_price' => ['numeric', 'nullable', 'min:0', 'greater_than:min_price'],
]
```